# Из-за чего на самодельном движке происходит это?

Tags: php

В общем, при написании своего движка, столкнулся с проблемой, заключается она в том, что написав такой простенький код:

```
include 'system/cfg.php';
$main_file = fopen($theme."/main.php", "r"); while (!feof($main_file)) {
    $line = fgets($main_file);
    $news = str_replace('{titlepage}',' '.$title.'',$line);
    $opphp = "?";
    $link = " include_once('temp/my/temp.php'); ";
    $news = str_replace('{template_link}',$link,$news);
echo($news, $link); } fclose($main_file);
```

У меня на страничке этот код:

```
$link = " include_once('temp/my/temp.php'); ";
        $news = str_replace('{template_link}',$link,$news);
```

Выводится как будто я написал комментарий к коду.

```
<!--? include('temp/my/temp.php'); ?-->
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить!
Если что, то в cfg.php хранится основная информация, а в main.php код выглядит так:

```
<? {template_link} ?>
```

PS за дополнительной информацией в комментарии ) + Движок - НЕ DLE!

Comment: вы ожидаете, что добавив куда то строковый литерал, содержащий `include`, он вдруг магическим образом потом выполнится, или что? зы: как по мне, лучше бы вам забыть про написание своего движка, и почитать литературу для начала, и другие "движки" изучить. ибо это какая-то лютая штука

Comment: Всё таки, хочется узнать ответ как это правильнее сделать :)

Comment: То, что мне нужно побольше теории я и сам знаю, только устал искать, да и гугл в последнее время меня "не понимает"

Comment: Возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125789/run-php-and-html-code-from-a-string) вам нужно. А [здесь](https://habr.com/post/215139/) ещё варианты.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена)